# Equivalent of NULLIF in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to pick up different field if an intended field is empty (null) in a `FOREACH` statement. Is something like `NULLIF` (from SQL) in Pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a [bincond](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#arithmetic) and [null operators](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#null_operato).  You can use it like:

```
DUMP A ;
-- (foo,)
-- (,bar)
-- (bing,bang)
-- (,)
-- (bosh,)

B = FOREACH A GENERATE ($0 is not null? $0 : $1) AS result ;

DUMP B ;
-- (foo)
-- (bar)
-- (bing)
-- ()         <-- Note this value is a null
-- (bosh)
```